# how to Use Default LoginWithFacebook Button in my code

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5

here is my code which is running properly but I want to use LoginWithFacebook default button which is provided by facebook.
Is there any image provided by facebook then please give me suggestion.
thankx in advance.....

```
 #import "FacebbokViewController.h"
    #import "UserAppAppDelegate.h"

    @interface FacebbokViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation FacebbokViewController

    - (id)init
    {
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
// button which I have used

        UIButton *login=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100, 200,80)];
        [login setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

        [login setTitle:@"login With facebook" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [login setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [login addTarget:self action:@selector(loginWithFacebook) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:login];



    }

//  method which excute on my button click

    -(IBAction)loginWithFacebook{

        UserAppAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                @"email", nil];
        if(!appDelegate.session.isOpen)
        {

            // create a fresh session object
            appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
            [FBSession setActiveSession: appDelegate.session];

            [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                               allowLoginUI:YES
                                          completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

                                              [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
                                          }];

        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"hi");
        }


    }

    - (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState) state error:(NSError *)error
    {
        // If the session was opened successfully
        if (!error && state == FBSessionStateOpen){
            NSLog(@"Session opened");

            [self userData]; // method created to fetch user’s data.
            // Show the user the logged-in UI
            // do all the things as you have the info you requested from facebook
            return;
        }
        if (state == FBSessionStateClosed || state == FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed){
            // If the session is closed
            NSLog(@"Session closed");
            // Show the user the logged-out UI
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];

        }

        // Handle errors
        if (error){
            NSLog(@"Error");
            NSString *alertText;
            NSString *alertTitle;
            // If the error requires people using an app to make an action outside of the app in order to recover
            if ([FBErrorUtility shouldNotifyUserForError:error] == YES){
                alertTitle = @"Something went wrong";
                alertText = [FBErrorUtility userMessageForError:error];
                [self showMessage:alertText withTitle:alertTitle];
            } else {

                // If the user cancelled login, do nothing
                if ([FBErrorUtility errorCategoryForError:error] == FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled) {
                    NSLog(@"User cancelled login");

                    // Handle session closures that happen outside of the app
                } else if ([FBErrorUtility errorCategoryForError:error] == FBErrorCategoryAuthenticationReopenSession){
                    alertTitle = @"Session Error";
                    alertText = @"Your current session is no longer valid. Please log in again.";
                    [self showMessage:alertText withTitle:alertTitle];

                    // Here we will handle all other errors with a generic error message.
                    // We recommend you check our Handling Errors guide for more information
                    // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors/
                } else {
                    //Get more error information from the error
                    NSDictionary *errorInformation = [[[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey"] objectForKey:@"body"] objectForKey:@"error"];

                    // Show the user an error message
                    alertTitle = @"Something went wrong";
                    alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Please retry. \n\n If the problem persists contact us and mention this error code: %@", [errorInformation objectForKey:@"message"]];
                    [self showMessage:alertText withTitle:alertTitle];
                }
            }
            // Clear this token
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];


        }
    }

    -(void)showMessage:(NSString*)alertMessage withTitle:(NSString*)alertTitle
    {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertTitle
                                    message:alertMessage
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    }

    -(void)userData
    {

        // Start the facebook request
        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"id,email" forKey:@"fields"] HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *result, NSError *error)
         {
             //if(!error){

    //             NSLog(@"result %@",result);
                 NSString *fbid =result[@"email"];
                  NSLog(@"result %@",fbid);
             //}
         }];
    }
```

Comment: button image in facebook resource bundle

Comment: Use `FBLoginView` to show facebook login or logout button.

Comment: you also can download facebook button image and create an image button instead of using simple button

Comment: @Bhumeshwer sir i Have to use Loginwith facebook not login or logout

Answer (score 1):

you can use FBLoginView to have the the functionality as your requirement , you can use like this

```
FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
loginView.frame = YOURFRAME;
[self.view addSubview:loginView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `FBLoginView` in the Facebook SDK. [Official link/tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login-tutorial). In the later part of the tutorial, implementing custom views and logging in with API calls is also covered. But note that you would have to design your button on your own in the latter case.